# Opening and viewing the contents of a big .ttl file in R

Tags: r, ttl

i'm new with quantitative softwares but i'm trying to open a big .ttl file in R but I can't visualize its content. My objective is to open it and visualize all the content inside. Does anyone can help? Thanks

I tried to open it with rvest because rrdf is no more available, and then i used redland package but it openes it in html language and not in natural language. My objective is to see what there is inside it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Luca Biserna! I am a little confused by what you are asking. You ask about opening a `.ttl` file, but then you mention `rvest` which suggests to me that you have not even downloaded the file in order to attempt to open it in R? If that's the case, delete the [tag:ttl] tag, since your problem is about scraping a website and not (yet) about how to open the file in R. Please share the code you have attempted, including actual warnings/errors. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on _reproducibility_. Thx!

Comment: (Also add [tag:rvest], as that seems appropriate.)

Comment: I downloaded the file and I tried to open it inside R. The problem is the language in which it is opened: i used the rvest library and redland package but I can't open it in a proper way to see in normal language the data that it contains. So the question is: how to open a ttl file in R in order to read and see what there is inside?

Comment: Okay. Once a file is downloaded, `rvest` had nothing to do. Do you have a sample of this file? Is it text and something you can add to a [code block] in your question? Or can you add a link to a file here?

Comment: here you can find the file download. Let me know. Thank you. https://dataverse.no/file.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.18710/2CPQHQ/6N7JA7

Comment: I'm not proficient with reading/using RDF files, but this definitely has nothing to do with `rvest` (which is only about scraping data, you aren't doing that). If you get no luck here (I'm out of ideas), you may reach out to the `rdflib` package authors to see if it's a problem using that package.

Comment: Otherwise, are you able to open it using python or other softwares?

Comment: It's out of my wheelhouse, sorry, I don't know.